# What is the default size of the Ubuntu app icon?

Tags: icons, .desktop

What is the default size of the Ubuntu  app icon?

Comment: Please split your questions into multiple posts. It makes it easier to answer.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We're sorry, but Ask Ubuntu is not a forum, but a Question & Answer site: it works best if you ask one question, so you can receive one answer. When you ask multiple questions, you need to find one expert versed in multiple areas, which becomes unlikelier the more questions you put into, well, one question! ;-) So please, split up your question into multiple questions and drop me a comment so I can answer one of your questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The developer guide on the Ubuntu's official site says the software store require 256x256px size, maybe you need a larger one.

[Ubuntu Developer Guide - Creating a good icon](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/publish/creating-a-good-icon/)

Comment: For the debian package structure, you should find it here https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/ch-pkg_basics.en.html